# jQuery selection via array notation among multiple elements

Tags: jquery

While reading the jQuery [documentation about the jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) I came upon this line:

Alternatively, because the jQuery object is "array-like," it supports array subscripting via brackets:

```
// Selecting only the first 'h1' element on the page (alternate approach)
var firstHeaderElem = $("h1")[ 0 ];
```

I tested this out using three paragraphs with the jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $("p")[0];
    $("button").click(
    function()
    {
        t.fadeOut();
    });
});
```

It doesn't work. Is this because using array notation doesn't really return a jQuery object, thus the methods are not available?

Comment: Did you try `$(t).fadeOut()?`

Comment: It works. @likeitlikeit is right: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/2SVsr/

Comment: yeah typo now working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the array notation you are getting the native DOM elements back, not the jQuery "wrapped set". Your example would work if you did `$(t).fadeOut();` instead. If you wanted to get the first result of a set without shedding the jQuery goodness, you would do `$('p').eq(0);`